# Different parameters value in .ini file for different runs

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can I have different parameters value defined in `.ini` file for each repeat in `omnet` using `cmdenv`? I have repeat value as 4 and trying to have different value of `accidentStart` and `accidentDuration`.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:parameter-studies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. And shouldn't. The whole point of repetition is that all parameters have the same value, just the RNGs are seeded differently. So you get a different sample of the same distribution for every result value.

What you're looking for are *iteration variables*.
Something like this:

```
**.accidentStart = ${100, 200, 350}s
```

This will generate 3 runs without repetition, and 12 runs with `repeat=4`.

and if you add

```
**.accidentDuration = ${duration=300, 450, 600..1800 step 600}s
```

this will multiply the number of runs by another factor of 5.

By default, iteration variables produce a Cartesian product of their respective assigned sets of values. But there are ways to change this, consult the manual for how.